# How to conditionally change order of Screen in React-Navigation Stack Navigator without navigation prop?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-navigation

I have skippable auth screens in my stack navigator, I am trying to achieve following scenarios:

1. how do I open Home screen on 'app open' if user has skipped auth flow.
2. while surfing app if user clicks on 'login' > 'login screen' > 'logs in' then how do I open previously opened screen instead of reseting it to Home screen.

my current flow is something like this.

```
return isSIgnIn || skippedAuth ? <Main/> : <Root/>
```

this approach takes user to "Home Screen" after login.

Comment: You can use history.go(-1)